# Use stored properties when creating an HTML Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, sidebar

Using a sidebar, I get user input and save it as a script property. Next time the sidebar is loaded, I'd like to check if the saved property exists. If so, display it instead of the text entry box.

I know to use:

```
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().myFunction()
```

Honestly, I have tried so many different things at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried, I want to load values in the sidebar if they exist. If they do not I want it load a text entry box, that is what it does by default.

Edit - Adding Code

```
function loadSidebarValues() {
  if (dateText != 'ErrorStuff') {
    var div = document.getElementById('dateValue');
    div.innerHTML = dateText;
    var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error');
    errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
    $('#dateText').val(
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('dateColumn')
    );
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById('sidebarValues');
    div.innerHTML = "";
    var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error');
    errorDiv.innerHTML = 'There was an error.';
  }
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperties({
    'dateColumn': 'dateText',
  });
  Logger.log("date: " + userProperties.getProperty('dateColumn'));
}

function onLoad(){
  if (PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('dateColumn') != null) {
    loadSidebarValues();
  };
}
```

Comment: If you have different users for the same Apps Script file, then you may want to use "UserProperties" and not Script Properties.  If you use Script Properties to associate a setting with a user, then you must have a way to determine what user is using the sidebar.  Do you have code that captures the current user?  Then you could have a separate property (key) for every user.  Typically, I wouldn't use Script Properties for user settings, but if you need to directly access and edit the data set of user settings yourself, that might be a reason.

Comment: I am a bit embarrassed about my lack of knowledge on it. I know apps script fairly well, but haven't used much HTML in my projects.

Most of my attempts are just chunks of stuff I find by Googling. I will try to get them posted in a bit.

Comment: Where is this code located? Your sidebar's `.html` file? Or your `.gs` file(s)? JQuery and document are not valid in Google Apps Script `.gs` files, and unless you've stubbed `PropertiesService` in your sidebar `<script>` code, that isn't valid there either.

Comment: I assumed you figured this out? https://kurtkaiser.us/how-to-code-a-html-user-interface-in-google-apps-script/

Answer (score 1):

You can write server code to retrieve `UserProperties` value, then run the HTML script to get that value as instructed in File-open dialogs
 section in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

What they do:

1. `getOAuthToken` in `Code.gs`
2. Call that function in `Picker.html` by this code:

   ```
   function getOAuthToken() {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
         .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
   }
   ```
3. `createPicker` method from `withSuccessHandler` take token value from `getOAuthToken` in first step.

You can use the same pattern for your own case.

Comment: Thanks for this, will test it out ASAP.

Comment: ~function loadValues() {
  if (dateText != 'ErrorStuff') {
    var div = document.getElementById('dateValue');
    div.innerHTML = dateText;
    var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error');
    errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
    $('#dateText').val(
       PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('dateColumn'));
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById('sidebarValues');
    div.innerHTML = "";
    var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error');
    errorDiv.innerHTML = 'There was an error.';
  }
}